# Was Incursio really weaker than Grand Chariot, or was Wave just delusional?

Tags: akame-ga-kill

Wave states with great confidence that Incursio is weaker than Grand Chariot, because Incursio was a prototype for Grand Chariot, etc.

The early clashes between Wave and Tatsumi can lead the viewer to such conclusion, but Incursio's has the ability to evolve (from the beast it was made of), while Grand Chariot doesn't.

If you watched to the finale, we can see that

> Tatsumi causes Incursio to evolve so much during the fight against Shikoutazer that it even gains the ability to fly. While it is enough to defeat the emperor, unfortunately not enough to save Tatsumi's life.

Considering this, I don't think that Incursio was the weaker one. Is it so?

Comment: It says that all of the 48 imperial arms are equal in strength

Answer (score 8):

Currently there is no actual way of knowing this, especially not in the anime variety as this bends off from the manga's story quite a bit.

> Wave states that Incursio is the prototype of Grand Chariot, meaning it was created after Incursio. (ch 18, p 36) (ep 10)
>
> Its full capabilities, however, have yet to be revealed and it is therefore unknown if it is more powerful than its predecessor, Incursio.

But assuming that Incursio's Adaptation & Evolution are limitless, we can most likely state Incursio to be the stronger armor. But as we get to know in the manga *(do not believe this is shown in the anime)* it also has huge side-effects

**spoiler from the manga**

> However because Tatsumi forced Incursio to evolve rapidly to increase his strength, Incursio started to manifest in one of Tatsumi's eyes. After being examined by a doctor, he reveals that the armor has started to bond with him. He also states that after a few years Tatsumi could use it without overdoing it like Bulat. Now at the risk of being devoured by Incursio, Tatsumi can only transform 3-4 more times before Incursio consumes Tatsumi.

Answer (score 7):

Rather than evolving, Incursio adapts to its user. Tatsumi just happened to have huge potential, which lead to Incursio evolving along with him.

If we think back to the days where Incursio belonged to Bulat, its only ability apart from the obvious strength enhancing one which it shares with Grand Chariot, is its invisibility. Bulat had owned Incursio for many years longer than Tatsumi ever had.

Also, we know next to nothing about Grand Chariot's own abilities. For all we know, it might be the same as Incursio, only much younger and thus less "experienced".

Comment: Nice answer! :-) I didn't read the manga, but was very disappointed with how much Incursio "evolves" in the anime. :-( Perhaps I was expecting too much having seen many shounen anime where the protagonist becomes too OP (whereas AGK is supposed to be a more "realistic" take on things). :-|

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Incursio can be one of the strongest teigu, even though they told us that all 48 Imperial Arms were the same in strength and power. But take note of the following conversation during one of Night Raid's meetings:

> **Tatsumi**: Which is the strongest imperial relic?
> **Najenda**: That would depend on compatibility and how it was used.

So if it depends on the wielder, then Incursio in Tatsumi's hands could be stronger than Grand Chariot in Wave's hands. Incursio in Tatsumi's hands also defeated the Shikoutazer, the most powerful Imperial Arm, so yes, Incursio was stronger than Grand Chariot.

Answer (score 0):

Grand Chariot lack the ability to evolve, removing the risk of losing control or being devoured. Hence it is the final product. That does not mean it is necessarily stronger. Take the toy brand Nerf Guns for example, the original guns are extremely powerful and dangerous but they are designed with a stopper to limit the power making it safer, not necessarily better.

Answer (score 0):

Just to point out final episode proved that Incursio was overall stronger then Grand Chariot, being able to infinitely evolve. In the final episode all it took was one hit with the laser to stop Wave while Tatsumi got hit and kept going envolving his armour to compete with the most powerful Imperial Arms in Akame Ga Kill.

Answer (score -1):

I mean, I see why Incursio could be seen as the stronger and better teigu, but of Grand Chariot is the prototype, IE, the finished, best/most recent version, then who says it can't compete with Evolved Incursio, or even surpass it. All I'm really saying is we haven't seen as much of Grand Chariot as we have Incursio, thus, leading us to believe that, if we haven't seen it happen, it's not possible. So just keep an open mind. Besides, Wave was the only person to weild two Teigu with ease whenever it would normally kill the user, so keep Wave as a factor since he is the user, not just the Teigu itself.